# Google maps add infowindow listener on zoom change

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to add a infowindow to each marker I have and have the infowindow open when the zoom has changed.
I have tried add a standard onclick infowindow and it works, but the "zoom_changed" does not work.

Here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NextNine customer map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="500">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }

       .labels {
     color: black;
     background-color: #6699FF;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100px;     
     border: 2px solid #6699FF;
     white-space: nowrap;}
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jquery-xml2json-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.xml2json.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
    <script>
var markers = [];
var map = null;
var counter =0;
var counter_part =0;

var contencts = new Array();
contencts [0] = "NextNine89";
contencts [1] = "NextNine69";

function initialize() {
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(35.890026,-5.523652);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: chicago,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  $.get('Customers.xml', function(xml) {
      var jsonObj = $.xml2json(xml);
        $.each(jsonObj.Marker, function(){
            var stat = this.status == "Critical" ? 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png' : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png';
                 var mark = {
                        title: this.title,
                        latitude: this.latitude,
                        longitude: this.longitude,
                        icon: stat
                        }
                markers.push(mark);
        });
        for(var i=0; i< markers.length; i++){
          var lon = markers[i].longitude;
          var lat = markers[i].latitude;
          var image = markers[i].icon;
          var custname = markers[i].title;
          PlaceMarker(lat,lon, image, custname); 
        } 
});     

function PlaceMarker(lat, lon, image, custname) {

     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
     var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: myLatlng,
       map: map,
       icon: image,
       labelContent: custname,
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
     });

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'Site Info:'});

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);});
}

function recenter ()
{
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[counter].latitude,markers[counter].longitude);
    map.setCenter (location);
    map.setZoom (9);
}

function centerback()
{
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(35.890026,-5.523652);
    map.setCenter (location);
    map.setZoom (3);
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  recenter();
  if(counter==(markers.length-1))
  {
    counter=0;
    counter_part=0;
    centerback();
  }
  else
  {
    if(counter_part==5)
    {
        centerback();
        counter_part=0;}
    else
        {
            recenter();
            counter++;
            counter_part++;}
  }

}, 15000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Every X seconds I zoom in on a different marker, when I zoom in I would like to open a infowindow. Once I zoom to a different marker I want the infowindow to close.

Comment: Markers don't have `zoom_changed` event. Insted, bind that event to map. However, this will change your code's behaviour and you might need to review your code.

Comment: If I bind the event to map, will I able to control which infowindow will be opened ?

Comment: I told that, you should think which infowindows will be opened on map zoom change. Or you can tell more specifically about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Every X seconds I zoom in on a different marker, when I zoom in I would like to open a infowindow. Once I zoom to a different marker I want the infowindow to close.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mqdtj/) about your problem.

Some notes about what I've done different and what you should do more:

1. You are pushing `markers[]` array some information, but **it's element are not Google Maps Marker Object**. Therefore, it's better pushing `MarkerWithLabel` objects to that array since we are using them in passing to infowindow `open()` method.
2. Since we don't know information which marker will be opened according to zoom information, I made infowindow global and change its content dynamically in your `recenter()` function.
3. We are getting marker objects from array we only need to display infowindow on current selected marker. So `zoom_changed` event isn't needed anymore.

In my fiddle, I created a JSON object which is as same type with what you get from XML file. So you will need to adapt your `$.get()` method.

Moreover, in my local computer, this code worked without problem but in fiddle, I have problem with the first marker, its center is got focused well but infowindow is opening on the second marker's top.